# How can I submit to Springer? What is the format

Tags: publications, journals, computer-science, paper-submission, journal-workflow

I already published in Arxiv one article, and now I want to submit to springer's journal "International Journal of Computer Vision".

In the section 'about' they provide a Latex macro.. I don't know what is latex, so, my doubt is if I can use a simple word document to submit, and If there are a convention about the content format like introduction > methods > conclusion..

I appreciate your help. If I'm not clear I can answer here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can see the submission guidelines [here](https://www.springer.com/journal/11263/submission-guidelines). The parts that specifically address your questions are (emphasis mine):

> Manuscripts should be submitted in LaTeX. Please use Springer’s LaTeX macro package and choose the formatting option “twocolumn”.
>
> The submission should include the original source (including all style
> files and figures) and a PDF version of the compiled output.
>
> ...
>
> **Word files are also accepted.**

and

> MSWord: The journal **does not provide MSWord templates** for your manuscript. Please consult each section of the Instructions for Authors to ensure all components of your article have been properly included (references, table, figures, etc). If accepted, your article will be formatted by our production team.

It is recommended to use LaTeX (and I think it would be a good idea to learn it if you plan to stay in the field, it should not take very long to reach an adequate level of proficiency), but if you must, it allows you to use Word. However, no templates are provided for formatting. As suggested above, you could go through the entire document to understand the expected format, particularly related to metadata such as the title, author list, abstract, references etc. How you structure the content of the paper, however, is up to you and the common conventions in your field.

Comment: Why latex is recommended? It's worth?

Comment: @Gilberto From the subfields of CS I am familiar with, it is extremely common and standard, and many top venues do not offer any option other than latex for submission. So it may definitely be worth it, depending on your goals.

Comment: If I write something wrong, in relation to the expected format, they send me back to correct?

Comment: @Gilberto That may depend on venue and I don't have personal experience with this, but my guess is minor formatting issues will not be a problem, at least before acceptance.